# listview only printing one line, instead of whole file?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm working on project, where i have to read a .csv file, where each line of the csv file contains 14 fields. however, i can only manage to print the first line with listview. i simply cant get it to print more than one line and i have no clue why.

this is my code:

```
private void listView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var path = @"C:\Universitet\Privat\testfil.csv";

        using (TextFieldParser csvParser = new TextFieldParser(path))
        {
            csvParser.CommentTokens = new string[] { "#" };
            csvParser.SetDelimiters(new string[] { ";"});
            csvParser.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = true;
            

            //skipper kolloner
            csvParser.ReadLine();

            int i = 0;
            ListViewItem rows = new ListViewItem();
            while (!csvParser.EndOfData) {
                //læser linje og pointer bevaeger sig til næste linje 
                string[] fields = csvParser.ReadFields();
                rows.SubItems.Add(fields[0]);
                rows.SubItems.Add(fields[1]);
                rows.SubItems.Add(fields[2]);
                rows.SubItems.Add(fields[3]);
                rows.SubItems.Add(fields[4]);
                rows.SubItems.Add(fields[5]);
                rows.SubItems.Add(fields[6]);
                rows.SubItems.Add(fields[7]);
                rows.SubItems.Add(fields[8]);
                rows.SubItems.Add(fields[9]);
                rows.SubItems.Add(fields[10]);
                rows.SubItems.Add(fields[11]);
                rows.SubItems.Add(fields[12]);
                rows.SubItems.Add(fields[13]);
                
            }
            listView1.Items.Add(rows);
        }
    }
```

Furthermore, the first line will only show if i actually click on the empty space, instead of just showing on load as it is supposed to.

this is the output of the code:
[output of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IT4oZ.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your line is declared before the loop, so it is edited each time.

Change to this :

```
// Call this method when you want to populate your listview
private void PopulateMyListView()
{
    // if you call this method multiple times, don't forget to remove the olds rows
    listview1.Items.Clear();

    var path = @"C:\Universitet\Privat\testfil.csv";

    using (TextFieldParser csvParser = new TextFieldParser(path))
    {
        csvParser.CommentTokens = new string[] { "#" };
        csvParser.SetDelimiters(new string[] { ";"});
        csvParser.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = true;
        

        //skipper kolloner
        csvParser.ReadLine();
        
        while (!csvParser.EndOfData) {
            //læser linje og pointer bevaeger sig til næste linje 
            string[] fields = csvParser.ReadFields();

            ListViewItem row = new ListViewItem("A NEW LINE !");
            row.SubItems.Add(fields[0]);
            row.SubItems.Add(fields[1]);
            row.SubItems.Add(fields[2]);
            row.SubItems.Add(fields[3]);
            row.SubItems.Add(fields[4]);
            row.SubItems.Add(fields[5]);
            row.SubItems.Add(fields[6]);
            row.SubItems.Add(fields[7]);
            row.SubItems.Add(fields[8]);
            row.SubItems.Add(fields[9]);
            row.SubItems.Add(fields[10]);
            row.SubItems.Add(fields[11]);
            row.SubItems.Add(fields[12]);
            row.SubItems.Add(fields[13]);

           listView1.Items.Add(row);
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: obviously it have to be used inside the loop

Comment: You are a legend, thank you so much

Comment: @AndreasRavnholt Be careful, I forgot to move listView1.Items.Add(row); that was at the end of the code. I edited my answer. By the way, I removed the int i = 0; because I don't see it's purpose.

Comment: you should also use ListView.BeginUpdate/EndUpdate before and after loop

Comment: Yes, @Selvin is right. If you have a big file, you can specify BeginUpdate so that the display of the listview is not updated while you fill it in and EndUpdate when you are done. This way you avoid the freeze of the interface.

Comment: @UserNam3 that makes a lot of sense, everything is being read correctly now - however, do you know why i still have to click on the whitespace for it to show, instead of just showing when i run the program?

Comment: @AndreasRavnholt what whitespace ?

Comment: @UserNam3 When i run the program, all it really shows is the table, with the column names, but no content in the table. i have to press on the table, in order for something to show up in it. so its like the code for reading data into listview1 is only being executed when i press the table.

Comment: Did you add columns to your listview ?

Comment: Yes, and the column names also show correctly, but the data in them does not

Comment: okay, I understand. That's because you do that in a method that gets called when the index of the listview changes. Moves the code in the constructor for example or calls it by pressing a button.